# rails json gem cannot convert nil into hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rubygems

Just deployed a rails application to my BlueHost server, installed all of the gems and launched the application with Passenger.

However, when I go to the app I see:

[image]

Any idea why the error `can't convert nil into Hash` is coming up? I've also tried to downgrade the `json` gem from `1.7.7` to `1.7.5`, but with no success. (I changed it back, don't worry)

**Update 1**

I thought maybe it hadn't migrated my database at this point. However I just migrated it and am still having the same problem.

**Update 2**
To clarify, I am using **Ruby 2.0.0-p0** and **Rails 4.0.0.beta1**

**Update 3**
Here is my Gemfile as requested.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0.beta1'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.0.1'
gem 'haml'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'rvm-capistrano'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 4.0.0.beta1'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0.beta1'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.3.0'
end

group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Comment: Well you are on the absolute bleeding edge of RoR, so that might not be helping, but really we need to know what argument you're passing to this gem. I'm guessing the argument can't be nil

Comment: Honestly I have no idea why the `json` gem is even needed. I do not convert anything to json myself. I'm not sure what would be calling it.

Comment: I am using the bleeding edge of Rails though, wanted to utilize some of the new Rails 4 features like Strong parameters.

Comment: I'll try to move back to Rails 3 and see what happens, but if anyone else has any ideas, please feel free to comment.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I assumed you were another hopeful entrepreneur trying to do something in RoR, posting vague errors involving gems. I don't know what your server-side is like but I assume you've run bundle and rake and all that right?

Comment: Haha, fair assumption. Yep, I've run `bundle` and all the gems install successfully, and I've successfully migrated the database with `rake db:migrate`. Any idea how I can track down what is happening? You're probably right that it's a Rails 4 problem.

Comment: I assume it works locally, I guess the only thing left is to start hunting through the logs, maybe report it on github? Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, works great locally. Just downgraded it to 3.2.13 and same issue...

Comment: I would then have to say that the issue is your server, maybe some dependencies are forbidden, for example on heroku you are only allowed to use PostgreSQL and its adapters...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We changed the server hosting from BlueHost to DigitalOcean. It's working now... not sure what BlueHost was doing to restrict it.

Comment: The issue's moot now, but I'd be curious in the first line of that backtrace that hit your app's code (even if it's generated by `rails new`).